# I am trying to change letters (ABC) into numbers (123) in xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am very new at Xpath and am struggling with some functions. Here is a basic version of the XML file. I want to change the id into an attribute and then change the letter B into a number. I am writing the output as XML.

```
<artists>
  <artist>
    <id>B</id>
    <name>John Sunday</name>
  </artist>
</artist>
```

Here is what I have done in my XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="artist">
   <artist>
     <xsl:attribute name="id">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="id"/>
     </xsl:attribute>
     <name><xsl:value-of select="name"/></name>
   </artist>

<xsl:template match="id">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate('BCD','BCD','123')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

and then get the following output:

```
<artist id="123">
<name>John Sunday</name>
</artist>
```

where I just want it to be:

```
<artist id="1">
<name>John Sunday</name>
</artist>
```

followed by the next artist being "2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change this

```
<xsl:template match="id">
  <xsl:value-of select="translate('BCD','BCD','123')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="id">
  <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'BCD','123')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

As your template matches the `id`, the `.` is the current value of the `id`.

If this is applied to the example input XML

```
<artists>
  <artist>
    <id>B</id>
    <name>John Sunday</name>
  </artist>
  <artist>
    <id>C</id>
    <name>John Monday</name>
  </artist>
  <artist>
    <id>D</id>
    <name>John Tuesday</name>
  </artist>
</artists>
```

the following output is generated:

```
<artist id="1">
  <name>John Sunday</name>
</artist> 
<artist id="2">
  <name>John Monday</name>
</artist> 
<artist id="3">
  <name>John Tuesday</name>
</artist>
```

For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/translate
And as further explanation: for the syntax `translate(string, toReplace, replacement)` the `<xsl:value-of select="translate('BCD','BCD','123')"/>` in the template matching `id` assigns as value  the translation of `BCD` into `123`, as the first parameter - `string` - is not the current `id` value, but the string `BCD`.

Answer (score 3):

Or just:

```
<xsl:template match="artist">
    <artist id="{translate(id,'BCD','123')}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
    </artist>
</xsl:template>
```